# Angular: How to set input to its default value

Tags: angular, typescript

i'm using angular 7 and i need help about validations.
i'm having trouble after i fill all those inputs and when i hit the button, all those input fields come empty again witch is correct, but the validation messages comes out after that.
i just wanna do is simply when everything is correct, after a press the button the validation messages don't come out.

Here's my code.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bgbzem

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is reference to the form in order to have easier access to all controls within that form.

For that reason I added reference to the form and `ngSubmit`.

```
<form (ngSubmit)="adicionar(f)" #f="ngForm">
  ...
</form>
```

With this in your `adicionar` method within component class you have access to all values of the form along with access to `resetForm` method which resets form data along with `touched` and `dirty` flags.

Another important is checks of errors and deciding when to show them. Usually you want to do that when form is submitted or field has been touched/dirty.

Example:

```
<small
  *ngIf="Tipo.invalid && (f.submitted || Tipo.touched || Tipo.dirty)" 
  class="invalid-feedback">
  <span *ngIf="Tipo.errors.required">Tipo is required</span>
</small>
```

Supporting documentation
https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#template-driven-validation

Working StackBlitz -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nk6zga